# OpenTracing not activating for Sleuth-Zipkin in Spring Boot App

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, opentracing

Spring Doc says

> Spring Cloud Sleuth is compatible with OpenTracing. **If you have OpenTracing on the classpath, we automatically register the OpenTracing Tracer bean**. If you wish to disable this, set spring.sleuth.opentracing.enabled to false

I have the below dependency in my POM.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${version.opentracing.spring}</version>
    </dependency>
```

But, I get the following print out it the logs when I try to print the trace and span information : **tracer: NoopTracer**

```
2018-11-19 12:12:03.938 [{X-B3-SpanId=4cd8eed6fe759bd1, X-B3-TraceId=5bf25b3bd0714ae54cd8eed6fe759bd1, X-Span-Export=true, spanExportable=true, spanId=4cd8eed6fe759bd1, traceId=5bf25b3bd0714ae54cd8eed6fe759bd1}] DEBUG ahallim-1ef960 --- [nio-7070-exec-1] a.h.w.RestaurantController               : tracer: NoopTracer
2018-11-19 12:12:03.939 [{X-B3-SpanId=4cd8eed6fe759bd1, X-B3-TraceId=5bf25b3bd0714ae54cd8eed6fe759bd1, X-Span-Export=true, spanExportable=true, spanId=4cd8eed6fe759bd1, traceId=5bf25b3bd0714ae54cd8eed6fe759bd1}]  INFO ahallim-1ef960 --- [nio-7070-exec-1] a.h.w.RestaurantController               : active span: null
```

Why am I getting a NopTracer? Why isn't Brave being registered automatically as promised? Am I doing something wrong?

I am using

> Finchley.SR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Finchley.SR2 train of releases. Once I upgraded to the latest Spring Boot and Spring Cloud versions, the issue fixed itself.

I removed the opentracing-spring-cloud-starter dependency and am now just using

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentracing.brave</groupId>
        <artifactId>brave-opentracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```